# .NET Core: Array class does not contain definition for ConvertAll

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, visual-studio

I'm currently following https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference for my C# learning process. I copy and paste the given code for C#. Here I need to convert String array to Int Array. Example code uses `Array.ConvertAll(a_temp,Int32.Parse)` to do that. But in my Visual Studio Community 2017 IDE it gives error for ConverAll method.

> 'Array' does not contain definition for ConvertAll

But when I refered

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx

  it says it Exists(ConvertAll)  in System namespace.

[image: My IDE views]

As you can see my IDE does not give suggestion for ConvertAll Method. I'm not sure this is a beginners dumb mistake. So I'll add my code in IDE here (Almost same code in hackerrank)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Solution
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[][] a = new int[n][];
        for (int a_i = 0; a_i < n; a_i++)
        {
            string[] a_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            a[a_i] = Array.ConvertAll(a_temp, Int32.Parse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tested in my vs2017 community and can compile, what .net framework version are you using?

Comment: Hello @Menuka Ishan
have you tried System.Array.ConvertAll()

Comment: @DivyeshGauswami `System.Array.ConvertAll` not working

Comment: @LeiYang I think it's  Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1590.0 This is the output I got when I ran `csc` in command prompt\

Comment: so are you using .net core or not, what project type are you creating?

Comment: @LeiYang I think problem was that I used .NET core console application. It worked when I used .NET Framework. Thank you

Comment: So have you got any alternate solution ? @MenukaIshan

Comment: @DivyeshGauswami below answer works for me. I created new project with .NET Framework

Comment: That's Fine! Sorry my suggestion didn't  works for you. @ManukaIshan

Comment: No worries. I think if we use `using System` we don't need to use `System.Array.ConvertAll` just `Array.ConvertAll`Just like import library in java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you are working in `.NET Core` project and there is not such method in `.NET Core` yet. You could either create new project with `Full .NET Framework 4.6.x` or use `Enumerable Extensions` to convert your array:

```
string[] a_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
a[a_i] = a_temp.Select(s => Int32.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked when I used `Console App(.NET Framework)` instead of `Console App(.NET Core)`.

Comment: How do I know when to use .NET core application or .NET Framework? Or is it Best practice to always choose .NET Framework?

Comment: .NET Core is relatively new framework and it runs on Linux and Mac OS. It also supports newer ASP.NET MVC 6 and web applications are significantly faster on ASP.NET Core. So it very much depends on the requirements. I would go for .NET Core for new projects.

Comment: But in a situation like this? Only thing we can do is Open new project with full .NET framework ? Or is there a way to extend the .NET core? Like we do in java. Add dependencies?

Comment: @MenukaIshan, .NET Core 1.x and NetStandard 1.x has limited API. There is no way to extend it today to use `Array.ConvertAll` or other missing APIs. Later this year NetStandard 2.0 and .NET Core 2.0 will be released and they will have more API covered. There are way to achieve same behavior as I showed, but otherwise you need to use Full Framework.